# How to remove a specific <option> in a .post

Tags: jquery

Here is my Jquery code:

```
$('#unblockButton').click(function () {
                var blockedlist = [];
                var count = 0;
                $('#blockedList > option:selected').each(function () {
                    count = count + 1;
                    blockedlist.push(this.value);
                    $(this).remove();
                });
                unblockDistributor(blockedlist.join(', '), count)
            });

    <select multiple="multiple" class="listBox" name="blockedList" id="blockedList">
        <option title="John Doe (3)" value="21">John Doe (3)</option>
        <option title="Jane Doe (4)" value="24">Jane Doe (4)</option>
        <option title="Jason Doe (5)" value="23">Jason Doe (5)</option>
     </select>
```

What I want to do is to save myself a page refresh and remove the  element in the Jquery, would be even better to do it only if the post was successful.

```
function unblockDistributor(ID, count) {
            var distref = '<%= dictlanguage("DistributorRef") %>';
            var alertStr = ''
            if (count > 1) {
                alertStr = 'You have removed ' + count + ' ' + distref.toLowerCase() + 's from your block list.';
            } else {
                alertStr = 'You have removed ' + count + ' ' + distref.toLowerCase() + ' from your block list.';
            }
            $.post('message_center_functions.asp', { action: "unblock", unblockID: ID }, function (data) {

            })
            .success(function () { alert(alertStr); })
            .error(function () { alert("There was an error while trying to make this request;  If it persists please contact support"); });
        }
```

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to change this.remove to $(this).remove();.  If anyone can post an answer on how to remove it only if the post is successful that is what I am looking for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code it should only be removed **if `$.post` was successful**:

http://jsfiddle.net/3TVZa/

```
$('#unblockButton').click(function() {
    var blockedlist = [];
    var count = 0;
    $('#blockedList > option:selected').each(function() {
        count = count + 1;
        blockedlist.push($(this).value);
        $(this).addClass('toBeRemoved');
    });
    unblockDistributor(blockedlist.join(', '), count)
});

function unblockDistributor(ID, count) {
    var distref = '<%= dictlanguage("DistributorRef") %>';
    var alertStr = ''
    if (count > 1) {
        alertStr = 'You have removed ' + count + ' ' + distref.toLowerCase() + 's from your block list.';
    } else {
        alertStr = 'You have removed ' + count + ' ' + distref.toLowerCase() + ' from your block list.';
    }
    $.post('message_center_functions.asp', {
        action: "unblock",
        unblockID: ID
    }, function(data) {

    }).success(function() {
        alert(alertStr);
        $('.toBeRemoved').remove();
    }).error(function() {
        alert("There was an error while trying to make this request;  If it persists please contact support");
        $('.toBeRemoved').removeClass('toBeRemoved');
    });
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly and taught me a neat trick in the process, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

change `this.remove` to `$(this).remove();`

```
       $('#unblockButton').click(function () {
            var blockedlist = [];
            var elems = []; // added this array
            var count = 0;
            $('#blockedList > option:selected').each(function () {
                count = count + 1;
                blockedlist.push(this.value);
                elems.push($(this)); // added elem to array
            });
            unblockDistributor(blockedlist.join(', '),elems, count) // passing the elems array
        });
```

then

```
   function unblockDistributor(ID, elems, count) {
            var distref = '<%= dictlanguage("DistributorRef") %>';
            var alertStr = ''
            if (count > 1) {
                alertStr = 'You have removed ' + count + ' ' + distref.toLowerCase() + 's from your block list.';
            } else {
                alertStr = 'You have removed ' + count + ' ' + distref.toLowerCase() + ' from your block list.';
            }
            $.post('message_center_functions.asp', { action: "unblock", unblockID: ID }, function (data) {

            })
            .success(function (){ elems.remove(); //removing the options })
            .error(function () { alert("There was an error while trying to make this request;  If it persists please contact support"); });
        }
```

Comment: ooooooooooops.. little late.. :P

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the node by selecting it in remove method like this :

```
$('#blockedList').remove('[value="' + ID + '"]');
```

Comment: This would work, but ID can be 21(would work), or it can 21, 23, 24 (would fail).  As in the each loop it build into an array which is then turned into a string as it is passed into the post function.  Would it be easier to also pass in the actual array, and then loop through that in the success function?

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed it was an joined array passed in parameter.
I think a better solution would be to keep the array when calling unblockDistributor, and only join the array in the post call.
then in your success callback you could then parse values as you proposed and call remove selector on each value.

Comment: i'm curious to know why -1 my answer ? Adding class to focus items is not a better solution.
If concerned person can answer me. Thanks.